# how to open the generated pdf in new tab on symfony 4

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, knp-snappy

on my `Symfony 4` app, i have a botton that used to generate pdf from html using `knp snappy bundle` but the generated pdf get displayed in the same page , so i'm looking for a way to open the generated pdf on new tab, is there a way to accomplish that ? 
Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you post the code?

however you should add the **target="_blank"** where the pdf is opened like this:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://your_url.html">Link to the route that generates the pdf</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

here is my receipt action , i created creat new receipt and then i print it :

```
/**
 * @Route("/receipt/{id}", name="receipt_index", methods={"GET","POST"})
 * @param Bill $bill
 * @return Response
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function newReceipt(Bill $bill): Response
{

    $receipt = new Receipt();
    $date = new \DateTime('now');
    $receipt->setBill($bill);
    $receipt->setBillCost($bill->getCost());
    $receipt->setBillDate($bill->getPrintDate());
    $receipt->setBillNumber($bill->getId());
    $receipt->setClientName($bill->getClient()->getFullName());
    $receipt->setReceiptDate($date);
    $receipt->getBill()->setStatus(true);
    $binary = $this->container->getParameter('knp_snappy.pdf.binary');
    $snappy = new Snappy($binary);

    try {

        $newDate= $date->format('Y-m-d');
        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entityManager->persist($receipt);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $html= $this->renderView('bill/receipt.html.twig', array(
            'receipt'=>$receipt,
        ));


            $pdf=$snappy->getOutputFromHtml($html,array(
            'orientation' => 'portrait',
            'enable-javascript' => true,
            'javascript-delay' => 1000,
            'no-stop-slow-scripts' => true,
            'no-background' => false,
            'encoding' => 'utf-8',
            'lowquality' => false,
            'page-width' => '8cm',
            'page-height' => '12.40cm',
            'margin-left'=>0,
            'margin-right'=>0,
            'margin-top'=>0,
            'margin-bottom'=>0,
            'images' => true,
            'cookie' => array(),
            'dpi' => 300,
            'enable-external-links' => true,
            'enable-internal-links' => true,
            )
        );
    return new Response($pdf,200,array(
        'Content-Type'          => 'application/pdf',
        'Content-Disposition'   => 'inline; filename="recu-'.$newDate.'.pdf"'
    ));

    } catch (Exception $e){
        dump($e);
    }

}
```